# VBA - Find paragraph starting with numbers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using a VBA script to try to find the starting number of a paragraph (they are list items not formatted as such - not trying to format, just find the numbers).

```
1. First Item
2. Second Item
No number - don't include despite 61.5 in paragraph.
25 elephants should not be included
12. Item Twelve, but don't duplicate because of Susie's 35 items
```

Is there any way to say in VBA "If start of paragraph has 1-2 numbers, return those numbers". In regex, what I'm looking for is `^(\d\+)\.`

Here is a working bit of VBA code - haven't figured out how to CREATE the excel file yet, so if you go to test create a blank test.xslx in your temp folder. Of course this may be simple enough that testing isn't necessary.

```
Sub FindWordCopySentence()
On Error Resume Next
Dim appExcel As Object
Dim objSheet As Object
Dim aRange As Range
Dim intRowCount As Integer
intRowCount = 1

' Open Excel File
If objSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     'Change the file path to match the location of your test.xls
    Set objSheet = appExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    intRowCount = 1
End If

' Word Document Find
Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
With aRange.Find
    Do
        .ClearFormatting
        ' Find 1-2 digit number
        .Text = "[0-9]{1,2}"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            ' Copy to Excel file
            aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
            aRange.Copy
            aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 1).Select
            objSheet.Paste
            intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
        End If
    Loop While .Found
End With
Set aRange = Nothing

If Not objSheet Is Nothing Then
    appExcel.workbooks(1).Close True
    appExcel.Quit
    Set objSheet = Nothing
    Set appExcel = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go quite a bit simpler and just check the first few characters of the paragraph:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
        With para.Range
            If (.Characters(2) = ".") Or (.Characters(3) = ".") Then
                If IsNumeric(para.Range.Words(1)) Then
                    Debug.Print "Do something with paragraph number " & _
                                 para.Range.Words(1) & "."
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next para
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, shortly after I submitted that question I realized I had to switch to For Each Paragraph for other reasons. This fits nicely in that bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach, which obviates the need to test every paragraph:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrOut As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^13[0-9.]{1,}" ' or: .Text = "^13[0-9]{1,}
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    StrOut = StrOut & .Text
    ' or: MsgBox Split(.Text, vbCr)(1)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox StrOut
End Sub
```

As coded, the macro returns the entire list strings where there may be multiple levels (e.g. 1.2). Comments show how to find just the first number where there may be multiple levels and how to extract that number for testing (the Find expression includes the preceding paragraph break).